# python and package manager are broken

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, python

After upgrading Ubuntu from `15.04` to `16.04`, `python` and `package manager` are broken.

When running `apt-get update` I receive the message `use apt-get -f install`, but when running this command I get following error:

```
Get:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python amd64 2.7.11-1 [137 kB]
Fetched 137 kB in 0s (1.700 kB/s)
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.11-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"  __main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
 exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
 import struct
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
 from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct 
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
  python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried solutions proposed in other posts:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure python-minimal
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: python-minimal is broken or not fully installed

sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.11-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
   exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
   import struct
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
   from _struct import *
  ImportError: No module named _struct
  dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
  Errors were encountered while processing:
    python-minimal
```

`reinstall python-minimal` didn't work.

Also when trying to run `apt-get remove|autoremove`, I'm getting the same `python error`

**UPDATE 1**

I just tried:

```
apt-get download python-minimal
sudo dpkg --install ./python-minimal_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb
```

but I'm still getting the same error

**UPDATE 2**

I mange to remove the broken `python` packages by doing this:

```
apt-get download synaptic
sudo dpkg --install ./synaptic...
```

and then I deleted the packages using `synaptic`, but the problem is that now after deleting them, every time I want to install something, the package manager automatically tries to install `python2.7-11` and `python-minimal-2.7-11`, but he doesn't succeed and I'm getting the error again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 LTS python-minimal package error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026780/error-upgrading-ubuntu-16-04-lts-python-minimal-package-error)

Comment: @Melebius These two questions cannot be properly merged because they have different accepted answers so I voted to leave this question open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before upgrading to `Ubuntu 16.04`, I had `python2.7.5` installed and I assume that during the upgrade, `Ubuntu` tried to upgrade `python` from `2.7.5` to `2.7.11` but it failed and so I ended up having the files of `python2.7.5` still on the laptop and `python2.7.11` partially installed.

I solved my error by doing this:

- removed the partially installed `python2.7.11` as explained in `UPDATE2` of my question
- deleted the folder of `python2.7.5`

  ```
  sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/
  ```
- reinstalled `python2.7` -> `python2.7.11` and its dependencies were installed correctly
- done! everything works now!

Comment: Uhmmyeah... don't  remove `/usr/lib/python2.7/`. It's generally a *bad* idea.