# Cannot uninstall this broken dependency

Tags: 14.04

```
 apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dictionaries-common
Suggested packages:
  wordlist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dictionaries-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
68 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/186 kB of archives.
After this operation, 775 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 59883 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dictionaries-common_1.27.2_all.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/dict/words to /usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common by dictionaries-common'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common' with
  different file '/usr/share/dict/words', not allowed
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dictionaries-common_1.27.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 new dictionaries-common package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dictionaries-common_1.27.2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the answers I gave might be able to sort this for you. Basically means removing it.

[Error upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 LTS python-minimal package error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026780/error-upgrading-ubuntu-16-04-lts-python-minimal-package-error/1079287#1079287)

The example was for a python package, but it is able to remove any other package that is giving you a problem. 
Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: I delete this file cd/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common and upgrade it .It's work